# Mod_wsgi daemon mode not reloading web page templates

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache2, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I cannot reload django templates by touching the wsgi.py script located in my django application root/application name.

The script and project are located under /var/www, so I need sudo to execute touch.

I am running production apache2 server running a django website with mod_wsgi in daemon mode. I can collectstatics and make migrations, access database (without permission issues). I can also change the DEBUG flag in the settings. If I touch wsgi.py, it will put the production site into debug as expected, but the htmls are not loaded. Likewise I can update the static files, collectstatics, or modify the underlying models and see the changes live. Likewise I can use the commented code to retrieve what Daemon mode the swerver is running in. Its only the templates causing an issue. The settings file, wsgi.py, statics and python scripts are responded as expected.

Has anyone got any idea how to debug this?

virtualenv python3.8.12 apache2.4
mod_wsgi compiled for python3.8.12

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../")))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../app/")))

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mb.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

#def application(environ, start_response):
#    status = '200 OK'

#    if not environ['mod_wsgi.process_group']:
#      output = u'EMBEDDED MODE'
#    else:
#      output = u'DAEMON MODE'

#    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
#                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

#    start_response(status, response_headers)

#    return [output.encode('UTF-8')]
```

apache2 site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName app

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName ------removed for posting-----
        ServerAlias -----removed for posting------


        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mb

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mb>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /var/www/vhosts/mb/static
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mb/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mb/mb>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess mb python-path=/var/www/vhosts/mb python-home=/var/www/vhosts/mb/pyenv
        WSGIProcessGroup mb
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/mb/mb/wsgi.py

        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I did an scp copy into the directory with a new html and not a git push. The result? I used a recursive copy on scp with the -r flag. This created a subdirectory automatically. It confused the daemon. Removing this subdirectory fixed the issue, and touch worked fine.